# How to get the current logged-in user from Fluid?

Tags: php, html, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I need a way to get the current logged in user object from Fluid. I need it in Partials and Layouts, not only Templates, so I can't do this by getting it as an argument from a Controller class.

I already know how to do this from Typoscript, e.g. to get his/her name:

```
TSFE:fe_user|user|name
```

To get it from Php I use my own static function from my own extended FrontendUser class: User, called `User::getLogged()`. Could I call this function from a Partial? Or is there any other method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: Version 8.7.32.

Answer (score 4):

**TYPO3 10 Tutorial**

First of all, if you want to use your partials then you can call them via Templates layouts etc. You can give them some arguments as well. So if you want to call for example the menu partial you could do something like that if you want to pass some arguments:

```
<f:render partial="Menus/Menu" arguments="{user: user}"/>
```

or if you want to pass all the arguments

```
<f:render partial="Menus/Menu" arguments="{_all}"/>
```

---

Now if you are using your controller to get the user object there are better ways to do get your user in FrontEnd. You can use the [TYPO3 Context API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html) for that. You can build a ViewHelper for that which you can call it wherever you want.

First, you need to register your ViewHelper. Under **your_extension/ext_localconf.php**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fluid']['namespaces']['yourNamespace'] = ['YourVendor\\YourExtension\\ViewHelpers'];
```

Then under **your_extension/Classes/ViewHelpers/Data/UserViewHelper.php**

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;


class UserViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments,\Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)  
    {
       $output = $renderChildrenClosure();
       $userRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendUserRepository::class);
       $context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
       $userId = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'id');
       $user = $userRepository->findByUid($userId);
       $renderingContext->getVariableProvider()->add('loggedInUser',$user);
       
       return $output;
}
```

Then on your Templates/Partials/Layouts somewhere you can do the following:

```
<yourNamespace:data.user/>
```

And if you debug your variables `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` then you will that you have a new variable called `loggedInUser` and in there is your user object. You can use it wherever you want and get all the information you need.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time into responding in such a detailed and insightful way. It turns out we already have the logged-in user in the global variables, so I can simply retrieve it with fluid in-line notation ({...}). I found it by debugging {_all} as you said. Thanks for the explanations though. I also read about custom ViewHelpers in the documentation and thought they could be useful here, but I was confused by the `render` functions and the example, since I only needed Php for the logic, not for rendering anything.